# Call user func explanation

Tags: php

As the php manual say

- **call_user_func** — Call the callback given by the first parameter

> mixed call_user_func ( callable $callback [, mixed $parameter [, mixed
>   $... ]] )

- Calls the callback given by the first parameter and passes the remaining parameters as arguments.

I start to test this feature:

- Function must callable

**Example 1:**

```
<?php
   function my_callback_function() {
      echo 'hello world!';
   }

   call_user_func('my_callback_function');
?>
```

Example 1 return true. Bur what about the second parameter ($parameter) ?

**Example 2:**

```
namespace Test;

class Foo
{
    static public function bar()
    {
        echo "Hello world!\n";
    }
}

call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ . '\Foo::bar');  // true
call_user_func(array(__NAMESPACE__ . '\Foo', 'bar')); // true
call_user_func('Test\Foo::bar');  // false <error>
```

In this example, I left out the second parameter and he return TRUE.

**Example 3:**

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo "Hello world";
    }
}
if (is_callable(array('foo', 'bar'))) {
   call_user_func(array('foo', 'bar'));  
 }
```

Am confused because documentation say **"Call the callback given by the first parameter"**

All function examples above don't have any parameter, but documentation say he back first param. How can return if that param don't exist?

Comment: Documentation means the first parameter of `call_user_func` not of your actual called function. So the first parameter is the function name being called.
Also not the more flexible `call_user_func_array`

Answer (score 0):

The code `call_user_func( array('foo','bar') )` calls `call_user_func()` with a single parameter which is an `array`, but still a single parameter.

Comment: Yeah that confused me. taht param is one. 1st param = ``array('foo','bar')``, second param missing. That mechanisam is litle confused about this

Answer (score 0):

Anything that passes an is_callable test is eligible for passing to the first parameter of call_user_func and call_user_func_array. This includes:

A function name as a string

```
function test(){
    echo "Hello World";
}
call_user_func("test");
```

A static method

```
class A {
    public static function test(){
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
call_user_func(array("A", "test"));
```

A Instance method

```
 class A {
     public  function test(){
         echo "Hello World";
     }
}

$a = new A();
call_user_func(array($a, "test"));
```

A anonymous function/closure

```
$a = function(){ echo "Hello World"; } 
call_user_func($a);
```

Also note that in your above example:

```
call_user_func('Test\Foo::bar');
```

Yielded an error... this is becuase it was being run in the Test namespace so the function was being resolved as `\Test\Test\Foo::bar`  this would have worked had you done:

```
call_user_func('\Test\Foo::bar');
```